# Method that takes strongly typed property name as parameter

Tags: c#

I'd like to refactor these two methods, the only difference is the property on the currentUser object that gets updated (and the parameter name, but that's not important).

```
public User SaveBaselineModelTemplateId(int baselineModelTemplateId)
{
    using (var db = _contextFactory.GetContext())
    {
        var currentUser = db.Users.Single(x => x.Login == Environment.UserName);
HERE -> currentUser.BaselineModelTemplateID = baselineModelTemplateId; 
        db.SaveChanges();
        return currentUser;
    }
}

public User SaveComparisonModelTemplateId(int comparisonModelTemplateId)
{
    using (var db = _contextFactory.GetContext())
    {
        var currentUser = db.Users.Single(x => x.Login == Environment.UserName);
HERE -> currentUser.ComparisonModelTemplateID = comparisonModelTemplateId; 
        db.SaveChanges();
        return currentUser;
    }
}
```

I'd like a method that I could call like `SaveInt(ComparisonModelTemplateID, 42)` or `SaveInt(x => x.ComparisonModelTemplateID, 42)`. It seems like there is a way to do this using expression trees, but I couldn't find any exact examples of what I'm looking to do, thanks.

Comment: You have to consider whether that sort of refactoring will really make the code "better."  Yes, you get some code reusability, but probably at the cost of code clarity and speed (especially if you end up using reflection).

Comment: There are at least 6 int properties on my User objects, I think it's well worth it to have one method to do the updating versus 6 that have almost exactly the same code

Comment: Fair enough.  And I'll have to admit, I didn't anticipate a solution as clean as dasblinkenlight's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need an expression tree for this - a simple `Action<User>` would be sufficient:

```
private User ModifyAndSave(Action<User> modify) {
    using (var db = _contextFactory.GetContext())
    {
        var currentUser = db.Users.Single(x => x.Login == Environment.UserName);
        modify(currentUser);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return currentUser;
    }
}
public User SaveBaselineModelTemplateId(int baselineModelTemplateId)
{
     return ModifyAndSave(u => u.BaselineModelTemplateID = baselineModelTemplateId);
}
public User SaveComparisonModelTemplateId(int comparisonModelTemplateId)
{
     return ModifyAndSave(u => u.ComparisonModelTemplateID = comparisonModelTemplateId);
}
```

The two `public` methods above pass different action to the common `ModifyAndSave` method above. The common method takes an `Action<User>` which tells it what to do with the `User` object retrieved from the database before saving modifications.